# Angular 2 rc3 router-deprecated package issue

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-router

Welcome Angular 2 rc.3!

I use `project.json` from [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files) to configure my project, but when i run `npm install` i get follow error:

```
No compatible version found: @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.3
Valid install targets:
2.0.0-rc.2, 2.0.0-rc.1, 2.0.0-rc.0, 0.0.0-7, 0.0.0-6
```

Does anyone know what reason of that? Maybe quickstart doc out-of-date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think so its by mistake

try the last version of release

```
  "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
```

Comment: Yes, i still use v2.0.0-rc.2, but maybe there are a new module for routing instead of `router-deprecated`?

Comment: @user3272018 This package.json from this quickstart guide also loads "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7" so it appears it's inclusion is deliberate.

Comment: i added both "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2" & "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7", boom it's working :)..

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 RC3 brings back the new router.
But the Tutorial continues to mention router-deprecated.
Check out the Developer guide which has documentation on the latest Router:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

As mentioned in the comments, you can give it a try using

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7"
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm running rc.2, but with the new component router. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html. here's the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.6",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"systemjs": "0.19.31",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"contentful": "3.3.14"
```

}

i'm using the alpha6, cause i didn't got alpha7 working.
anyhow, if you starting new in a project, i would go for the new component router. the developer even recommend it: http://angularjs.blogspot.ch/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You guessed right, the QuickStart tutorial doc was in fact wrong, and the Pull Request handling this has just recently merged its commits. Should you go to the QuickStart docs again, you'll see it's been updated!

Here's the closed Pull Request:
https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/1727

So no worries, you were doing just fine!