# Angular2 Installation: no compatible version found

Tags: angular, npm

Problem in installation Angular 2
I already read the quickstart but still I cant install/start

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv C:....\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v 4.4.5
npm ERR! npm v3.9.6

npm ERR! no compatible version found: @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! valid install targets:
npm ERR! 2.0.0-rc.2, 2.0.0-rc.1, 2.9.9-rc.0, 0.0.0-7, 0.0.0-6
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! if you need help
```

this is the exact error in my command prompt . Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Open up package.json, and on or about Line 22 you'll find the following:

```
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
```

Change it to:

```
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
```

And save the file. That last part is important. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue opened yesterday.  It gives some insight into what to do.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9428

The answer at the bottom of this question also has info on how to use the new router in rc3, without having to downgrade to the deprecated rc2 version.

[Angular 2 rc3 router-deprecated package issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959130/angular-2-rc3-router-deprecated-package-issue)